# UItableViewCell Custom ContentView with Multiple labels and Need to Preserve selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, state-management, multipleselection

I have a `UITableView` with multiple `UILabel`s in each cell like a grid view. I added a `UIGestureRecognizer` to do some action on each of these labels (e.g. changing its background). Everything is working fine.

But the problem is whenever I scroll up or down, the labels that were selected in a cell loose their selection state. When I searched some people suggested that I create the cells with different cell IDs or use `UIScrollView` instead, but both methods will use more memory compare to adding multiple labels in a `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`.

How can I preserve the selection state of `UILabel`s in each cell when scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the selection state is necessary to accurately draw each cell, you should add properties for each label's state to the cell's backing model object.  Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can determine from the model object the proper selected state for each label:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexedPath*)path {
    CustomCell *cell; // trimmed for brevity
    CellModelObject *modelObject; // this would be pulled from an array, dictionary, or some other collection

    cell.firstLabel.selected = modelObject.isFirstLabelSelected;
    cell.secondLabel.selected = modelObject.isSecondLabelSelected;
    // etc.

    return cell;
}
```

As the table is scrolled and cells are reused, its state would be set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` regardless of what the cell previously showed.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is creating an nsmutablearray that stores the states of the label, and then using this array in `cellForIndexPath:` to set the background of the labels. This should work, but there may be a better solution out there that feel less like a hack.